# How to match characters from all languages, except the special characters in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a display name field which I have to validate using Ruby regex. We have to match all language characters like French, Arabic, Chinese, German, Spanish in addition to English language characters except special characters like *()!@#$%^&.... I am stuck on how to match those non-Latin characters.

Comment: Perhaps if you supplied some strings, showing sample input and sample output, people would be able to help more. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: You mean all letters of all alphabets?

Comment: @Bolt That's actually feasible if you have the right tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

- Create a regex with a negated character class containing every symbol you *don't* want to match:

  ```
  if ( name ~= /[^*!@%\^]/ ) # add everything and if this matches you are good
  ```

  This solution may not be feasible, since there is a massive amount of symbols you'd have to insert, even if you were just to include the most common ones.

---

- Use [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/) (see also: [Oniguruma for Ruby main](http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/)). This supports Unicode and their properties; in which case all letters can be matched using:

  ```
  if ( name ~= /[\pL\pM]/ )
  ```

  You can see what these are all about here: [Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Ruby 1.9, the `String` and `Regex` classes are unicode aware. You can safely use the Regex word character selector `\w`

```
"可口可樂!?!".gsub /\w/, 'Ha'
#=> "HaHaHaHa!?!"
```

Comment: Because `\w` is defined as `[0-9A-Za-z_]`.

Comment: Yes I know that, it is the reason behind it that defies me. (BTW. `\w` matches more than that in unicode)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that later versions of ruby (tried with 2.2.2) doesn't match e.g. 可口可樂 äåö as word characters ( \w ) anymore :(

Comment: I guess it matches `_` too because in programming languages `my_variable` is considered a single word.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby > 1.9.1 (maybe earlier) one can use `\p{L}` to match word characters in all languages (without the oniguruma gem as described in a previous answer).